# .Net Maui Android Community Toolkit Observable Object not available

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-android

Im building an .net maui ios and android app, i tried to implement the Maui Community Toolkit.MVVM. After that i wanted to use the Observable Object (Picture below). But VS tells me that net7.0-android isnt supporting that, any help here?
[image: VS Observable Object not available]

Reinstallation doesnt help

Comment: What's the version of your visual studio? And have you installed nuget `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` and nuget `CommunityToolkit.Maui`?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT VS Version 17.5.4 and Nuget 8.2.0
but :D today i started my PC and everything works fine.

Comment: Congrats. Have a nice day. :)